# Do equipment bonuses count if it exceeds 10 in a S.P.E.C.I.A.L. stat?

Tags: fallout-shelter

For example, if I have a dweller with max Perception (level 10) and I give him/her armor that boosts Perception by 3. Is his/her Perception level then counted as 13 or is it capped at 10?